# App of the day Android

Tags: google-play-store, nexus-4, chrome-for-android

When I click on the link in the "app of the day" to view the app offered every day it seems that before liking to the google play page it open an ads page that I am not able to view. It is right and normal?

Do I have to keep warning about it?

I use Nexus 4 with stock 4.4.4

Comment: What "app of the day" is this? Google Play doesn't have an "app of the day" feature.

Comment: "App of the day" is an Android app that offers a free app every day. This is not a feature of the Google Play

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't seem unusual to me that an app that commercially depends on tracking its users would send you to a website to track and count you, and then have that site redirect you to the real store page.

If you don't trust them not to misuse this tracking data, don't use the app.

Comment: I agree with you, I am only asking if is normal that I am not able to see ads, how can they earn money if I do not spend any time on promoted sites?

Comment: You're assuming that the page they're sending you to is supposed to show ads. More likely it's a page they use to track your visit, so they know which apps you are interested in.

Comment: @Ale you should run a logcat when using, see what's going on. Also use app detective to see inner workings of "app a day". You might not like what you find. Also what are the permissions used by the app,  are they allowing sensitive data to be seen and used?